# MySQL queries and intervals

Tags: php, sql, date, intervals

This is the toughest query I ever made:
http://robertr.pastebin.com/X4bG4pFp

```
"SELECT  `user`.`id` ,  `user`.`fname` ,  `user`.`lname` , 
YEAR(  `user`.`bday` ) AS  `bday_year` ,  `user`.`class_id` , 
( SELECT  `class`.`class_name` 
  FROM  `wp_class_classes`  `class` 
  WHERE  `user`.`class_id` =  `class`.`id`) AS  `class_name` 
FROM  `wp_class_users`  `user` 
WHERE MONTH(  `bday` ) = $month AND DAY(  `bday` ) = $day 
OR  `user`.`fname` = 
( SELECT  `name`.`names` 
  FROM  `wp_class_namedays`  `name` 
  WHERE  `name`.`day` =  '$month.$day'
  AND  `user`.`fname` =  `name`.`names` )
```

This query grabs data from three different database tables to check if there is someone in the database, who has a party today. And in Latvia we have Name Days too. Anyway, this query works well, and does its job well, but now I want to make it a bit cooler.

I want it to show, who will be having a party next week. You've probably noticed these emails that Facebook sends to you every weekend showing who has a birthday coming up.

But I just can't understand how to get at least that interval?

I remember that PHP has some good functions with which you can find on which day starts month and so on, but maybe here are some bright heart, and willing to help me kick me a bit faster forward.

Comment: Please post your relevant code here and not somewhere else, SO is made for displaying code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT
  `user`.`id`,
  `user`.`fname`,
  `user`.`lname` ,
  YEAR(`user`.`bday`) AS  `bday_year`,
  `user`.`class_id`,
  (
    SELECT
      `class`.`class_name`
    FROM  `wp_class_classes`  `class`
    WHERE  `user`.`class_id` =  `class`.`id`
  ) AS  `class_name`,
  CASE
    WHEN MONTH(`week`.`Date`) = MONTH(`user`.`bday`) AND
         DAY(`week`.`Date`) = DAY(`user`.`bday`) THEN 1
    ELSE 2
  END AS `event_type`
FROM  `wp_class_users`  `user`
  LEFT JOIN  `wp_class_namedays`  `name` ON  `user`.`fname` =  `name`.`names`
  LEFT JOIN  (
    SELECT CURDATE() + INTERVAL (1 - DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE())) DAY AS `Date`  UNION ALL
    SELECT CURDATE() + INTERVAL (2 - DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE())) DAY  UNION ALL
    SELECT CURDATE() + INTERVAL (3 - DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE())) DAY  UNION ALL
    SELECT CURDATE() + INTERVAL (4 - DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE())) DAY  UNION ALL
    SELECT CURDATE() + INTERVAL (5 - DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE())) DAY  UNION ALL
    SELECT CURDATE() + INTERVAL (6 - DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE())) DAY  UNION ALL
    SELECT CURDATE() + INTERVAL (7 - DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE())) DAY
  ) `week`
    ON CONCAT(MONTH(`week`.`Date`), '.', DAY(`week`.`Date`)) IN (
      CONCAT(MONTH(`user`.`bday`), '.', DAY(`user`.`bday`)),
      `name`.`day`
    )
WHERE `week`.`Date` IS NOT NULL
```

The user table is joined with the name day table, and the result set is then compared against the dates of the *current* week. The final result set lists only those users whose birthdays or name days happen during the week.

If you want to know about the events of, for example, the next week, you can simply change the intervals in the `week.Date` definitions as `8 - DAYOFWEEK...`, `9 - DAYOFWEEK...` etc.

One last thing is, instead of the correlated subquery in the select list you could use `INNER JOIN`, like this:

```
SELECT
  `user`.`id`,
  `user`.`fname`,
  `user`.`lname` ,
  YEAR(`user`.`bday`) AS  `bday_year`,
  `user`.`class_id`,
  `class`.`class_name`
FROM  `wp_class_users`  `user`
  INNER JOIN  `wp_class_classes`  `class` ON  `user`.`class_id` =  `class`.`id`
  LEFT JOIN  `wp_class_namedays`  `name` ON  ...  /* the rest of the above script */
```

---

The `event_type` column as defined above can tell you whether the event is a birthday or not, but it doesn't let you know whether it's both the Birthday and a Name Day for that particular person.

In case you would like to have that distinction, you could change the `event_type` definition like this:

```
CASE
  WHEN MONTH(`week`.`Date`) = MONTH(`user`.`bday`) AND
       DAY(`week`.`Date`) = DAY(`user`.`bday`) THEN 1
  ELSE 0
END +
CASE CONCAT(MONTH(`week`.`Date`), '.', DAY(`week`.`Date`))
  WHEN `name`.`day` THEN 2
  ELSE 0
END AS `event_type`
```

Now the result of the column would be:

- 1 – a birthday
- 2 – a name day
- 3 – both

Additionally, you could have `'B'` instead of `1` and `'N'` instead of `2` (and `''` instead of `0`). The results would be then `'B'`, or `'N'`, or `'BN'`. Not sure whether `+` can be used for concatenation, though. If not, put both `CASE`s into `CONCAT()`.

Comment: When I try to execute this query, I error:
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DAYS AS `Date` UNION ALL SELECT CURDATE() + INTERVAL (2 - DAYOFWEEK) DAYS ' at line 16

I don't really know, what's wrong there, because I never did some kind of intervals before so, if you could help me, I would appreciate it . Thanks.

Comment: @Robert: `DAYOFWEEK` should actually be `DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE())`. My fault, sorry. Fixed that.

Comment: Thanks for your effort, but I still getting the same error:

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DAYS AS `Date` UNION ALL SELECT CURDATE() + INTERVAL (2 - DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE' at line 16

Comment: @Robert: Changed `DAYS` to `DAY` in the interval expressions. Sorry again.

Comment: Hey, again, thanks for your effort :) And Thanks God, line 16 now is clear. But there is one more error in syntax. #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'varchar(2)) + '.' + CAST(DAY(`week`.`Date`) AS varchar(2)) IN ( CAST(MONTH' at line 24

Comment: @RobertR: Your question turns out to be a good lesson for me on MySQL syntax. :) Changed the concatenation expressions, please check.

Comment: Finnaly this is working! Thanks a lot, dude! :) I would love to buy you beer :) Cheers!

Comment: Anyway, is it possible to add in query, which party is that? Sign Birthday as 1, and Name Day as 2?

Comment: @RobertR: That's really nice of you. :) Added the `event_type` column to the query defined as you requested, and also suggested its alternative definition. Seems like there should be no more problems with syntax, but if there are just don't hesitate to let me know.

Comment: Well, I used your second example, where you can detect if its birthday, names day or both, but actually, didn't worked out as good as needed. Check this image: http://img571.imageshack.us/img571/5653/screenshotuvd.png I exported also birth year, month and day, and names day, (month.day)

Comment: @RobertR: That was an example of what 'good' can come out of careless copying & pasting. Forgot to change the references on the right sides of the comparisons (`week`.`Date` -> `user`.`bday`). Fixed now.

Comment: No worries, I checked already every SQL function, which you were used here, so I could understand, what the hell is happening there :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I get your query right, but the command `SYSDATE()` is mentioned in [the MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-options.html). You might want to try something like:

```
... where date = SYSDATE() + 7
```

(check the syntax, I come from Oracle ;) )

This will get the parties for the next 7 days.

Comment: I think, that these next seven days is nothing hard at all, but what about this week?

Comment: The correct link would be http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_sysdate. Due to the equality operator, this query (with the correct function) will only select one date instead of a week.

Comment: doin this in a function you can look for the acutal day of the week and from that point on you can do the "+7" i used above in a variable which takes it value from "this day" to "next sunday" which is like today = monday, sunday is in 6 (or 7 however you count it) days so the variable is +6 and with next week included +13 (6+7 = 13)

Comment: If you want "this week", you could use [DAYOFWEEK](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayofweek) to get the index of the day. Then you can do a WHERE birthday BETWEEN today-dayofweek, today+(7-dayofweek) to get birthdays for "this week". But why would you want to alert users of birthdays in the past? Unless their actual party is later ;)